# WPF storyboard animation repeats

Tags: wpf, blend, wpf-animation

I have a trigger that fires off an OptionsShow storyboard animation when a button is clicked.  This works with no problem.  When I click an options button that I created, I made a grid fade in over it, similar to a custom tooltip.  When the user leaves that grid, I make it fade out with the OptionsHide storyboard animation.  If I leave the grid and quickly hover over the grid before it completely goes away, the grid constantly flashes.

It seems that the constant flashing occurs because the initial hide animation cannot complete, but I can't seem to figure out how to debug this.  I don't have an "OnEnter" grid trigger to reshow the grid, so I'm not really sure when it shows the grid with opacity 100%, begins to fade and the constantly repeats this process.

If anyone has any experience with this, any help or info would be great.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OptionsShow">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OptionsHide">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <!--This is my button in my menu bar.  On click I show my tooltip grid.-->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OptionsShow}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <!--When I leave the tooltip grid, make the tooltip grid fade out.-->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave" SourceName="Border">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OptionsHide_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OptionsHide}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: I think what you may want here is a ToggleButton that reveals a Popup. I tried your code and saw the flashing, but when I moved the button out from underneath the border, the flashing effect stopped. So it's some weird thing with the mouse being over both controls. I'd drop it and go straight to the popup.

Comment: I believe that the issue was that when I leave the grid I fire the OptionsHide animation which sets visibility visible at the start.  When the animation completely disappears, we say "Hey, my mouse left the grid" (even though the grid went away from the mouse.)  Removing the initial set to visible and 100% opacity state fixed the issue.  If you move back and forth really quickly it probably fires the OptionsHide but with the previous state values instead of setting it to 100% each time.